# Rule based (data driven or config based) condition evaluation and calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am developing a discount calculator for a small grocery shop where they have a weekly offers displayed on sales counter. I need to develop a module in place which can evaluate offer conditions via a database or a config file.

Required rules:

> **Buy 2 Articles get 3rd of same value free** -- Shop bill will display
>
> ($50 X 3) = $150 Gross ------ Less $50 ------ $100 Net Payable 
>   ------- (**Applicable Offer Code**)
>
> **Buy Over *$xxx* amount *** and get **y** percent discount  -- Shop bill will display
>
> ($15 X 10) = $150 Gross ------ Less $15 ------  $135 Net Payable
>   (**Applicable Offer Code**)
>
> **Buy complete Kit  and get some flat discount *** -- Shop bill will display
>
> (Moneysaver pack blah blah) = $250 Gross ------ Less $20 ------ $230
>   Net Payable (**Applicable Offer Code**)

I tried using NCalc - Mathematical Expressions Evaluator for .NET (ncalc.codeplex.com), however its good for mathematical expressions in string, I am not finding the right way to branch it with my rule set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Windows Workflow Ruleset engine? This includes an editor as well as the ability to execute the rules (saved as xml in a db) at runtime.

To read more about this:

[A quick and dirty Rules Engine using Windows Workflow (Part 1)](http://www.sanderstechnology.com/?p=10166)

Comment: Thanks for your input, however the project I am working is c#  2.0 asp.net based application, which I doubt I am allowed to change the further.

Comment: You could execute the rule in C# in your ASP .Net code behind. You just need to manage the rules from a windows form app. Unless you wanted to manage the rule from ASP .Net too.